# SVN in NetBeans - Initial checkout not getting .svn directories

Tags: svn, version-control, netbeans

I've run through the NetBeans SVN project setup described here:
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html

However once it's checked out and imported into a project, the files aren't recognized as "versioned files" and I cannot make commits or compare, etc. When i right click a file in the project there is no "subversion" menu item. In fact, there are no .svn directories to be found.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

I have the most recent version of NetBeans for Mac OSX

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it. I had to set the proper preferences in NetBeans for specifying the svn home folder (/usr/bin).

Comment: where can I find the svn home folder preferences!

Comment: Could you please advise WHERE you 'set the proper preferences'? Currently this is a fairly unhelpful answer.